# MYSQL - Searching Criteria between 2 Combined Table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to ask something

I have 2 Tables and that`s are :

Table: General Inventory

[image]

and Table: Item_Master_List

[image]

now my goal here is to combine both tables based on ItemCode like

`...where GeneralInventory.ItemCode=Item_Master_List.ItemCode`

something like that. Now I did that and here is my full code for that

```
    Select GI.ItemCode,IML.Description,IML.StandardUOM,IML.StandardPrice 
from GeneralInventory GI,item_master_list IML where 
GI.ItemCode = IML.ItemCode
```

and here is the output

[image]

Now i have some criteria in my program and it looks like this

[image]

Here is my question. How can I applied the search feature in my MYSQL Command? How can i search the right data? using the combined columns? I tried this one but it results on multiple data redundancy

```
Select Distinct GI.ItemCode,IML.Description,IML.StandardUOM,IML.StandardPrice from 
GeneralInventory GI,item_master_list IML where GI.ItemCode = GI.ItemCode and 
IML.ItemCode = '' or IML.Description = 'Baking Soda 454 g' or IML.StandardUOM = '';
```

[image]

**Additional Question**

I have a another table called `Table: StockAdjust` and this is what it has

[image]

and now the best code that I have is this

```
SELECT DISTINCT GI.ItemCode,
                IML.Description,
                IML.StandardUOM,
                IML.StandardPrice
FROM GeneralInventory GI
INNER JOIN item_master_list IML
    ON GI.ItemCode = IML.ItemCode
WHERE IML.ItemCode = 'My Data' OR
      IML.Description = 'My Data' OR
      IML.StandardUOM = 'My Data'
```

The code above will combine Table `GeneralInventory GI` and `item_master_list IML` where `GI.ItemCode = IML.ItemCode` and filtering criteria using the ff. `IML.ItemCode, IML.Description and IML.StandardUOM`

Now my question here is how can I apply `NOT IN` command? like

`Above code.....AND GI.ItemCode NOT IN (select ItemCode in StockAdjust)`

How can I apply a code here that will do the code above and it will not include Data thats already in `StockAdjust`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused in your query because you placed the table join criteria into the `WHERE` clause, which also contains the logic for the search.  Instead, use explicit join syntax in your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GI.ItemCode,
                IML.Description,
                IML.StandardUOM,
                IML.StandardPrice
FROM GeneralInventory GI
INNER JOIN item_master_list IML
    ON GI.ItemCode = IML.ItemCode
WHERE (IML.ItemCode = '' AND
       GI.ItemCode NOT IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM StockAdjust) OR
      IML.Description = 'Baking Soda 454 g' OR
      IML.StandardUOM = ''
```

Comment: Sir is this applicable in like command? and Not IN? For example i will change `=` to `LIKE` and put `%` at the end of the word and add another command of `NOT IN (select Columname in TableName)` something like that?

Comment: @NyxAssasin This sounds reasonable.  Can you update your question with what you have in mind?

Comment: You didn't change anything, from what I can see.

Comment: Sorry Sir i put it at the bottom of the post

Comment: @Sir what do you think?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `LIKE`, or `WHERE NOT IN (...)`.  If you update your question with what you have in mind, I can give you a query for that.

Comment: Noted on that Sir

Comment: Sir I already updated the post this is the best that i can make TYSM for help and Time

Comment: @NyxAssasin I updated my answer per your requirements.  I grouped the two `ItemCode` conditions together, and then ORed this with everything else.  If it doesn't give you what you want, we may have to move things around a bit.

Comment: Update your question with sample data, showing how you want the query to obtain its result set.  Again, you are being unclear.

Comment: Sir I will update this post soon or create a new one with a detailed explanation very soon. Need to do something urgetn TYSM for the future help, anyway I will approve your question because some part of it helps me TYSM